# MinGw doesn't execute the program if file name has spaces

Tags: c++, notepad++, mingw, nppexec

So I use notepad++'s NppExec to directly compile and execute C++ files.

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
g++ "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART) -march=native -O3
NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)
```

This all works fine, now assuming I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    int main() {
        cout << "This is a normal statement" << endl;
        cout << "This statement uses endl;" << endl;
        cout << "This one has " << "multiple " << "chevrons" << "Cant tell huh?" << endl;
        cout << "This is a flush statement, this does not break line like this :" << flush;
        cout << "Me flush statement" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

I use the above executing code to compile it.....

Well this will work if the filename doesn't have any spaces like

```
Filename.cpp
New.cpp
example.cpp
nospace.cpp
```

But if I use spaces...

```
Hello World.cpp
This has a space.cpp
New error.cpp
```

It creates the following error:

```
NPP_SAVE: D:\C++\My Projects\New text.cpp
CD: D:\C++\My Projects
Current directory: D:\C++\My Projects
g++ "New text.cpp" -o New text -march=native -O3
Process started (PID=13652) >>>
g++: error: text: No such file or directory
<<< Process finished (PID=13652). (Exit code 1)
NPP_RUN: New text
; executing: NPP_RUN New text
- the specified file was not found
================ READY ================
```

Before you say that its because I have wrong in my code, it doesn't, that's the same file I encountered the problem with, the code is copy pasted....I named the file `Test File.cpp` and got the error but after changing to `TestFile.cpp` it didn't show the above error, also the code wasn't edited

Why and how do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is to simply not use spaces in your file names. It's only asking for problems.

But in this case have you tried using `"` around the NAME_PART variable?

```
g++ "$(FILE_NAME)" -o "$(NAME_PART)" -march=native -O3
NPP_RUN "$(NAME_PART)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `...-o New text` is the problem. This should compile:
`g++ "New text.cpp" -o 'New text' -march=native -O3`